# How to configure NGINX to render the sitemap.xml before Angular 5 Application loads

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, nginx-location

I have an Angular 5 application running on NodeJS server, and I would like to render my sitemaps at `website.com/sitemap/sitemap-cats.xml` and `example.com/sitemap/sitemap-dogs.xml`

My sitemaps are located at `/home/root/sitemap` folder.

I've tried to configure the location block at `/nginx/sites-available/default` as below, so it renders the sitemaps before the Angular application loads.

```
    # Sitemap Locations
    location /sitemap/sitemap-cats.xml {
            alias /home/root/sitemap/sitemap-cats.xml;
    }

    location /sitemap/sitemap-dogs.xml {
            alias /home/root/sitemap/sitemap-dogs.xml;
    }
```

The problem is that the configuration above did not work and the Angular application is showing 404 error for this reason.

Is it even possible to render these .xml files before the Angular app loads?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Sitemap Locations
location /sitemap/ {
        alias /home/root/sitemap/;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that too, then restarted nginx with 'sudo systemctl restart nginx' , but the sitemaps are still not showing up.

Comment: Try debugging nginx then. Do you use it just for static files, or as a proxy for nodejs as well ?

Comment: I also use it as a reverse proxy for nodejs.

Comment: The reverse proxy is setup using default website, not a vhost?

Comment: In that case you need to see what's nginx doing. Add `debug` at the end of the error log config like this:  `error_log /path/to/log debug;`, then make a request to the sitemap file and see in the log file what's happening